# Closed ideal in the hereditary C*-subalgebra

Tags: ideals, c-star-algebras

Let B is a hereditary C*-subalgebra of a C*-algebra A and J be a closed ideal of B, is AJA a closed ideal of A?

I do not find the definition of product of ideals in the C*-algebras, is it the same with the algebras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, No. Take $A = \mathcal{K}(\ell^2)$, the C* algebra of compact operators on $\ell^2$, and take $B = \mathbb{C}e_1\otimes e_1$, where 
$$
e_1\otimes e_1(e_j) = \delta_{1j}e_1
$$
(where $e_j$ are the standard basis). It is easy to see that $B$ is a hereditary subalgebra of $A$.

Now take $J = B$, then
$$
AJA = \text{span}\{a_1ja_2 : a_1,a_2\in A, j\in J \}
$$
is the algebra of finite dimensional operators, and hence is not closed in $A$.

In answer to your second question, yes, I believe the definition is the same as usual : If $I_1$ and $I_2$ are two closed ideals, then
$$
I_1I_2 = \text{span}\{a_1a_2 : a_j \in I_j\}
$$
In fact, one can show using approximate units that $I_1I_2 = I_1\cap I_2$

Comment: At Gerard J. Murphy's book: C*-algebras and operator theory, The proof of theorem 3.2.7 says AJA is closed ideal of A. Is it a mistake?

Comment: He probably takes the closure implicitly when he defines $AJA$. Not sure. I don't have the book with me.

Comment: Oh, yes. He defines the product of ideals as the closed linear span. Thank you very much.